# How to await the result of a function before continuing with the script?

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

I'm currently building a Nodejs script which should interact with a web server and a local network device. In order to make the program as reliable as possible I want to do a simple ping test to check if the network device can be reached.

```js
var ping = require('ping');

function pingtest(host) {
    ping.sys.probe(host, function (isAlive) {
        var msg = isAlive ? 'host ' + host + ' is alive' : 'host ' + host + ' is dead';
        console.log(msg);

        return isAlive;
    });
}

let pingSuccessful = pingtest('192.168.178.100');

console.log(pingSuccessful);
console.log('Should not executed before pingtest has finished.');
```

The output on the console is the following:

```
undefined
Should not executed before pingtest has finished.
host 192.168.178.100 is dead
```

The problem is that the script execution should pause until pingtest() has finished and returned the result. My goal is to console.error() a message and stop the script if this test failed. I already tried it with async await and the other code examples at https://github.com/danielzzz/node-ping but unfortunately this didn't work as expected.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply can not return from a callback. You can make use of Promise. Refactor the code like this:

```
function pingtest(host) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    ping.sys.probe(host, function (isAlive) {
        var msg = isAlive ? 'host ' + host + ' is alive' : 'host ' + host + ' is dead';
        console.log(msg);

        resolve(isAlive);
    });
  });
}

pingtest('192.168.178.100').then((pingSuccessful) => {
  console.log(pingSuccessful);
});
```

Or, you have to do everything inside `ping.sys.probe` callback.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I had this before but if you have any other code outside of the .then() method this is executed directly. I was wrong with my understanding of this behavior because I thought that calling such a function immediately pauses the execution until the result has come. Thank you!

Comment: If anything dependent on `pingSuccessful`, you have to put it inside `.then`. Because of javascript's non blocking nature, it would run all the synchronous code first without waiting for any async execution.

Comment: This was exactly my "mistake". Thank you for the explanation!

Comment: You can learn more about **javascript Promise (async/await)** to take full control over your code.

Answer (score 0):

yes this is async flow, you can use async/await to solve this issue

```js
function pingtest(host) {
    return newPromise((res, rej) => {
        ping.sys.probe(host, function (isAlive) {
            var msg = isAlive ? 'host ' + host + ' is alive' : 'host ' + host + ' is dead';
            console.log(msg);
            res(isAlive)
        });
    }
}

const startPing = async () => {
    let pingSuccessful = await pingtest('192.168.178.100');

    console.log(pingSuccessful);
    console.log('Should not executed before pingtest has finished.');
}

startPing()
```

Comment: `async` in-front of `pingtest` function is unnecessary since the function itself is return a promise.